# How to pass a variable as props inside the scope of another function's component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, scope, parameter-passing

I want to get a variable, called id in this case, and pass it to the onConfirm event... however, as you can see actually it is getting called by another's function call in setAlert
How can I do that?

```
const warningWithConfirmAndCancelMessage = (id) => {
    setAlert(
      <ReactBSAlert
        warning
        style={{ display: 'block', marginTop: '-100px' }}
        title='Are you sure?'
        onConfirm={(id) => {
          successDelete();
          handleDelete(id);
        }}
        onCancel={() => cancelDelete()}
        confirmBtnBsStyle='success'
        cancelBtnBsStyle='danger'
        confirmBtnText='Yes, delete it!'
        cancelBtnText='Cancel'
        showCancel
        btnSize=''
      >
        You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!
      </ReactBSAlert>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't pass id as parameter to onConfirm function

```
onConfirm={() => {
    successDelete();
    handleDelete(id)
}}
```

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: you are getting id from props, if you put the parameter name same as id, then you are not sending the props to handleDelete function

Comment: Thank you,@FL Alfie... You just saved my day and mood